# Replace the java Classes generated by Roaster to the appropriate Packages

Tags: java, jboss

I'm searching an API that generates Java source code from an input, I found almost a several api like Roaster JBoss and CodeModel. But My goal is to generate the Java Source and Place it in the approriate Packages. For the Roaster API, it Generates the code that i am looking for but just limited to display it. For the codemodel generator I can Replace the generated code to a file but I should Replace Them manually.

CodeModel Example:

```
    JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
    JDefinedClass dc = cm._class("Exemple");
    JFieldVar fv = dc.field(0, String.class, "Name");
    File file = new File("./file/classes");
    file.mkdirs();
    cm.build(file);
```

Roaster Example :

```
final JavaClassSource javaClass = Roaster.create(JavaClassSource.class);
    javaClass.setPackage("com.soprasteria.toolsandmeasures.modeling.loading").setName("Main");

    javaClass.addInterface(Serializable.class);
    javaClass.addField()
      .setName("serialVersionUID")
      .setType("long")
      .setLiteralInitializer("1L")
      .setPrivate()
      .setStatic(true)
      .setFinal(true);

    javaClass.addProperty("Integer", "id").setMutable(false);
    javaClass.addProperty("String", "firstName");
    javaClass.addProperty("String", "lastName");

    javaClass.addMethod()
      .setConstructor(true)
      .setPublic()
      .setBody("this.id = id;")
      .addParameter(Integer.class, "id");
    System.out.println(javaClass);
```

Can anyone Help Me please !

Answer (score 1):

You can save content generated in a java class.

An example:

```
public void createClass() {
    final JavaClassSource javaClass = Roaster.create(JavaClassSource.class);
    javaClass.setPackage("com.company.example").setName("Person");

    javaClass.addInterface(Serializable.class);
    javaClass.addField().setName("serialVersionUID").setType("long").setLiteralInitializer("1L").setPrivate()
            .setStatic(true).setFinal(true);

    javaClass.addProperty(Integer.class, "id").setMutable(false);
    javaClass.addProperty(String.class, "firstName");
    javaClass.addProperty("String", "lastName");

    javaClass.addMethod().setConstructor(true).setPublic().setBody("this.id = id;").addParameter(Integer.class,
            "id");

    try {
        File file = new File("src/main/java/" + "com.company.example" + "/" + "Person" + ".java");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(javaClass.toString());
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

I'm creating a project that aims to create classes. If you want to see:

https://github.com/robsonbittencourt/fixture-generator